# php dropdown options with times

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a starttime 16:15 and a end time 22:45 in my database

What I want is

```
<select>
    <option>16:15</option>
    <option>16:30</option>
    <option>16:45</option>
    ........
    ........
    <option> 22:30</option>
</select>
```

The last option is 15 minutes before endingtime

This is my code:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 22) {
    $m = 0;
    while($m < 60 {
        if($m == 0 or $m == 15 or $m == 30 or $m == 45) {
            ?>
                <option><?php echo $i.":".$m; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        $m++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
$startTime = "16:15";
$endTime = "22:45";

$startTimeObject = new DateTime($startTime);
$endTimeObject = new DateTime($endTime);

$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');

$times = [];
$currentTime = $startTimeObject;
while(true)
{
    if ($currentTime->format("H:i") === $endTimeObject->format("H:i")) {
        break;
    }
    $times[] = $currentTime->format("H:i");
    $currentTime->add($interval);
}

foreach ($times as $time) {
    echo "<option>$time</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: My solution will be correct for `$startTime="23:45"; $endTime="00:30"`

Comment: Thanx this is working for me but when the starttime is 16:15 and the endingtime is 02:00 this is not working

Comment: I tried to run with `$startTime="16:15"; $endTime="02:00"` and got the result: `16:15, 16:30, 16:45, 17:00, 17:15, 17:30, 17:45, 18:00, 18:15, 18:30, 18:45, 19:00, 19:15, 19:30, 19:45, 20:00, 20:15, 20:30, 20:45, 21:00, 21:15, 21:30, 21:45, 22:00, 22:15, 22:30, 22:45, 23:00, 23:15, 23:30, 23:45, 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, 01:45`. It seems to work...

Comment: And how can i only show the options when the current time is before or between the start and ending times

Comment: I don't understand. Is it question? What do you want to do? Please, give me incoming data and expected result (if you have question).

Answer (score 0):

By using the `DateTime` class you can access it's methods - of interest to you would be the method `add` - so by using a simple loop you can easily generate all the dates/times between start and end points.

```
$html=array();
$time_start='16.45';
$time_end='22.45';


$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$interval=new DateInterval('PT15M');

$start=new DateTime( date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $time_start ) ), $timezone );
$end=new DateTime( date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $time_end ) ), $timezone );

/* iterate through the chosen timeframe at an interval of 15 minutes */
$html[]='<select name="times">';
while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end ){
    $html[]='<option value="'.$start->format( 'H:i' ).'">'.$start->format( 'H:i' );
}
$html[]='</select>';

/* create menu as a variable */
$menu = implode( PHP_EOL, $html );

/* display the select menu where you wish in the HTML */
echo $menu;
```